# Add Trailing Zeroes After Decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

I am working with sku numbers that have the following 9 character structure:
a. a 3 digit number,
b. a period,
c. a five digit number.

An example: 505.12345.

A considerable % of the sku's end in 0. Examples: 505.12340, 505.12300, 505.12000.

I had no trouble keeping the trailing zeroes in SQL Server by setting the datatype to varchar after the migration from S3 -> SQL Server.  I used a new machine learning model in AWS Sagemaker that cut off the trailing zeroes prior to the migration to S3.

The example sku's above now look like: 505.1234, 505.123, 505.12

My question: what is the best way to add trailing zeroes to all sku's where LEN([sku]) < 9? I would prefer to keep the sku datatype as varchar.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a string, you can right-pad it with `0`s as follows:

```
left(sku + replicate('0', 9), 9)
```

Alternatively:

```
sku + replicate('0', 9 - len(sku))
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=20a12a92d3f6b1e6a680ba62a6b5c96a)**:

```
select sku, 
    left(sku + replicate('0', 9), 9) new_sku, 
    sku + replicate('0', 9 - len(sku)) new_sku2
from (values ('505.1234'), ('505.123'), ('505.12'), ('505.12345')) x(sku)
```

```
sku       | new_sku   | new_sku2 
:-------- | :-------- | :--------
505.1234  | 505.12340 | 505.12340
505.123   | 505.12300 | 505.12300
505.12    | 505.12000 | 505.12000
505.12345 | 505.12345 | 505.12345
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple way would be to `CAST` back to DECIMAL(9, 5) and then CAST again to CHAR(9)

Data

```
drop table if exists #tTable;
go
create table #tTable(
  dec_num       varchar(20) not null);
 
 Insert into #tTable values
('505.1234'),
('505.123'),
('505.12');
```

Query

```
select cast(cast(dec_num as decimal(9,5)) as char(9)) char_9
from #tTable;
```

Output

```
char_9
505.12340
505.12300
505.12000
```